# Strange behaviour about the sum of reputation points

Tags: support, reputation, reputation-history

I've found this strange behaviour about the sum of reputation points.

As you can see I've earned 10 points from an answer and 5 points from a question, the result should be 15 but, the sum seems to be 7.

Can someone explain why this happens?

P.s.
I've used the **bug** tag even if this problem is not totally reproducible, feel free to edit my question.

[image]

Comment: Check your reputation tab in your profile, or stackoverflow.com/reputation to see what else could've happened. Probably a deleted post or something that cost your 8 rep. If you're checking the rep tab in your profile, make sure "show deleted posts" at the bottom is checked.

Comment: A guess: 4 posts where you had an approved suggested edit were deleted.

Comment: @theB or, more likely, a post with an upvote and a downvote was deleted.